# How to create a matrix from a csv file?

Tags: python

I have been trying for two hours to create a table of values from a matrix and so far i have been able to create a column from the csv file. I know this is going to be easy for everybody, but when reading from a csv file, i cant seem to phrase it right so would people please put me in the right direction?

```
import csv

file = open('data.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(file)

for row in reader:
    print row[0]
```

so far I can only print out the first column, any advice guys?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? print the `data.csv`? if so, just do `print row` instead of print `row[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rU') as file:
    table = [row for row in csv.reader(file)]

print(table)
```

This will create a list of lists where each sublist is a row of the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

In your code *row* is a list of all the columns, So:

*row[0]* is the first column, *row[1]* is the second etc.

you can write:

```
print(str(row))
```

to print all the columns, or iterate over the with:

```
for column in row:
    print(column)
```

Comment: thanks man that is much appreciated much easier way to see that actually... so basically after

Comment: @entercaspa great. you can mark the answer as correct if its solved your question.